# how to escape special characters in xml without escaping xml tags(<>) in java

Tags: java, xml, stringescapeutils

I want to escape special characters in xml input.
I tried StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(xmlString) but it ends up escaping xml tags also(<>).
For example:

```
<Company>Test & Test</Company>
```

should normalized to

```
<Company>Test&amp;Test</Company>
```

Not

```
&lt;Company&gt;Test&amp;Test&lt;/Company&gt;
```

Comment: Why is the latter **not** the behaviour you want?  It seems to be exactly correct.

Comment: Hello, because this complete data will be wrapped in SOAP response envelope which is again xml.Also its a huge data and would be very difficult to read for the end users

Comment: In other words you are saying that your input XML is garbage? What about making that XML input non garbage to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense.  The first string is not valid XML, thus it's just a string.  If that string is to be used as data within valid XML, then escaping the entire thing is the correct thing to do.  The only other valid path here is to generate the input string as valid XML (as suggested by @fde).

Comment: No first string i.e. <Company> is actually a XML tag and value for that tag is Test & Test(just an example) so we need to escape special characters from value not the tag itself. Offcourse input XML is not garbage.CDATA wrapping is option which i can check in this case though.

Comment: But it **is** garbage - it's invalid XML.  There's no reasonable (general) way to convert invalid XML to valid XML.  You should escape the data **before** constructing the input "XML".

Comment: why **<Company>Test & Test</Company>** an invalid XML tag???Its generated from JAXB and also this xml is coming from webservice response wrapped in SOAP envelope :).Yes,I agree it should escape the data before constructing the input "XML".

Comment: If JAXB is generating invalid XML, then something is quite wrong.  Your SO question should be about **that**.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking how to automatically convert invalid XML to valid XML.  That's not a tractable problem, in the general case (imagine for example that you had an embedded `<` in the *actual* data).

The correct solution to this problem is to identify why you're starting with invalid XML, and fix **that** issue.